# PHP shell_exec() doesn't return the correct status

Tags: php, bash, shell-exec

I'm trying to run a sh script file from the php function `shell_exec()` but every time the return is uncorrect.

This is the sh file content:

```
if [[ -z $1 ]]
then
        echo "svn st: NULL"
else
        command=$(ssh -q USER@IP_OF_THE_REMOTE_NODE "svn st $1")
        if [[ -z $command ]]
        then
                test="svn st: OK"
        else
                test="svn st: KO"
        fi
        echo $test
fi
```

every time that I run this sh script from the shell the echo is ALWAYS correct.
The "$1" contains the working directory that I have to check.

But if I run the same script in this way:

```
$w_path = $working_path['path'];
$com = "sh /tmp/my_script_test.sh $w_path";

echo "content com ".$com;

$res = shell_exec($com);

echo "content res ".$res;
```

the last echo print ALWAYS "svn st: OK", that is correct for some `$w_path`, but completely uncorrect for others! Why? How can I find the mistake?

I don't think that is a ssh key problem cause I used a guide to resolve that and now I don't need to insert the password for the remote server.

Thanks 
Regards

Comment: Is you php script executed by the same user that executes the script? Enter `whoami` at the top of you sh file, your php script is probably run as www-data or apache (who does not have access to the remote server using a keypair).

Comment: Hi John thanks for your help. Yes in the second way the user is "Apache" and not "root", but I put the ssh key in var/www/.shh of the local server in the remote /root/.shh/authorized_keys. Do I have to do other things?

Comment: Change the command to `sh -x /tmp/my_script_test.sh $w_path`, so you'll see all the variable expansions.

Comment: Hi Barmar thanks for your help. I did as you said in your comment. Via shell I can see all the steps of the sh, via php I cannot see the same things, the shell exec return only the "whoami" and the usual "svn st: OK". It is frustrating! :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
        command=$(ssh -q USER@IP_OF_THE_REMOTE_NODE "svn st $1")
        if [[ -z $command ]]
```

to

```
        if ssh -q USER@IP_OF_THE_REMOTE_NODE "svn st $1"
```

and remember: *Whenever something doesn't work, it's because it's too complicated* (can't recall where I read that).